# auto check and assign the next alphabet to string

Tags: java, collections

There is a list of string how to check the last character is Alphabet and assign the next Alphabet.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("89A");
list.add("89B");
list.add("89H");
```

how to check and assign the next value as "89I" to the list.

Comment: That depends. What comes after `Z`? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You can dirtily accomplish this using [REGEX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and then casting the alphabet to integer (`int`) datatype, increment the value (by keeping a check of ASCII numbers range for alphabets) and re-cast it to character datatype and append to your String.